# Is there a way to hide 'Forced' public properties as if they were private?

Tags: angular, angular-directive, encapsulation

A frustrating trend in Angular evolution is forcing properties to be public in order to use them in templates. For example, in `[formControl]="myFormControl"`, `myFormControl` must be public or errors are thrown.

I think this is bad. One reason is if I want to prevent someone from creating a race condition by setting `myFormControl` directly, I either have to make it an accessor or I have to use tsdoc to beg future developers (namely myself) not to set it directly and to use the `setMyFormControl()` instead.

Is making `myFormControl` an accessor (`set myFormControl() { *buncha logic to prevent race condition* }`) a bad idea that will gum up change detection?

Anyone know another solution? One where I can have a public property to bind to the formControl directive but that hides it to discourage setting it directly from outside the class?

Anyone else dislike Angular's decision to force these properties to be public? I've yet to find an explanation for it that convinces me it's not just strong-arming developers to conform to someone's opinion of the role of encapsulation in Angular.

Comment: angular template is another class instance created to view something. because of this fact it is pretty logical to make fields public, as another class should access them

Comment: @Andrei Whether it is 'logical' to enforce this is debatable. I think it's more logical to allow end-developers to decide what to encapsulate in their own classes. Nobody's going to access this 'template class' in order go after custom public fields and JavaScript doesn't restrict anything via encapsulation. Thus a class CAN access another class' private fields, and the only thing in question is why you want to force developers to expose something simply because it's used in their template. To boot, the early versions of Angular didn't complain about private fields in templates. What changed?

Comment: I think earlier versions should have complained, if you were using AOT. this concept stayed the same and didn't change as far as I know. angular transforms the template to the piece of typescript code, which gets a class instance as a parameter. the rest of the type checking and everything is delegated to typescript compiler